# how to combine morethan 2 duplicate rows and sum the value in html table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I'm stuct with `html table`. I want to combine morethan 2 `duplicate rows` and sum the values in the duplicate rows.

My table table Example:

**Name**   **Amount** 
john         200
john         300
john         100
harish      400 
harish      400

Expected Result:

**Name**   **Amount** 
john         600
harish      800

I tried with below jquery code but it's only mergin two duplicate rows, if more than two duplicate row occures it's not merging but it's adding value and displaying duplicate row.

**Html Code:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>quantity</td>
        <td>expired</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="id">A</td>
        <td class="val">25</td>
        <td class="date">date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="id">A</td>
        <td class="val">25</td>
        <td class="date">date</td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="row">
        <td class="id">A</td>
        <td class="val">25</td>
        <td class="date">date</td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="row">
        <td class="id">A</td>
        <td class="val">25</td>
        <td class="date">date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="id">B</td>
        <td class="val">100</td>
        <td class="date">date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="id">C</td>
        <td class="val">35</td>
        <td class="date">date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="id">C</td>
        <td class="val">35</td>
        <td class="date">date</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
var first_row = '<tr class="row"><td class="id">NULL</td></tr>';
var rowCount = 0;
var rowSum = 0;
$.each($('.row'), function (index, curRow) {
    if ($(first_row).find('.id').text() != $(curRow).find('.id').text()) {

       if (rowCount > 1) {
            $(first_row).find('.val').text(rowSum);
            $(first_row).find('.val').css('background-color','silver');
            for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                $(first_row).next('.row').find('.val').remove();
                $(first_row).next('.row').find('.date').remove();
                $(first_row).next('.row').find('.id').remove();

            }
            }
       first_row = $(curRow);
        rowSum = 0;
        rowCount = 0;
    }

    rowSum += parseInt($(curRow).find('.val').text());
    rowCount += 1;
});

if (rowCount > 1) {
    $(first_row).find('.val').text(rowSum);
    $(first_row).find('.val').css('background-color','silver');
    for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        $(first_row).next('.row').find('.val').remove();
        $(first_row).next('.row').find('.date').remove();
        $(first_row).next('.row').find('.id').remove();
    }
}
```

**Result:**

**Name**  **quantity**  **expired**

A         100       date 
A          25        date 
A          25        date 
B         100       date 
C          70        date

Here I want in Name column All records should be `distinct` and quantity to be summed.

Please help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach using jQuery [.nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$('.row').each(function() {
  var thisId = $(this).find('.id').text();
  var sumVal = parseFloat($(this).find('.val').text());

  var $rowsToGroup = $(this).nextAll('tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('.id').text() === thisId;
  });

  $rowsToGroup.each(function() {
    sumVal += parseFloat($(this).find('.val').text());
    $(this).remove();
  });

  $(this).find('.val').text(sumVal);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    var json = {};
    //Sum up everything and erase
    $.each($('.row'), function (index, curRow) {                                    
        var curName=$(curRow).find('.id').text();   
        var curQty=$(curRow).find('.val').text();
        if (json[curName] != null){
            json[curName] += parseInt(curQty);
        } else {
            json[curName] = parseInt(curQty);               
        }
        $(this).remove();
    });
    //Rebuild table
    jQuery.each(json, function(name, val) {
        $('table').append('<tr class="row"><td class="id">'+name+'</td><td class="val">'+val+'</td><td class="date">date</td></tr>');
    });
```