# Javascript: Merging common table rows that have ruby code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

New to Javascript, I'm trying to make a function that will merge rows when they have the same value (in this case, the year (#pin)) and add their numbers(#price). My code doesn't work but it doesn't seem to cause any errors in my web page.

Table row html.erb:

```
<tr class="<%= payment_paid(f.paid)%>" id="paidrow">
     <td>
       <% if !f.paid %>
       <%= check_box_tag "pin_number[]", f.id, checked= !f.paid? %>
       <%end%>
     </td>

     <td id="pin"><%= f.year %></td>
     <td><%= f.quarter %></td>
     <td align="right" id="price"><%= number_to_currency(f.amount, unit: "", 
     precision: 2)%></td>
  </tr>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#paidrow").each(function() {
      var thisId = $(this).find('#pin').text();
      var sumVal = parseFloat($(this).find('#price').text());

      var $rowsToGroup = $(this).nextAll('tr').filter(function() {
        return $(this).find('#pin').text() === thisId;
      });

      $rowsToGroup.each(function() {
        sumVal += parseFloat($(this).find('#price').text());
        $(this).remove();
      });

      $(this).find('#price').text(sumVal);
    });
```

Code above was taken from the answer posted here:

[how to combine morethan 2 duplicate rows and sum the value in html table using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008224/how-to-combine-morethan-2-duplicate-rows-and-sum-the-value-in-html-table-using-j)

Comment: If you don't need to do this dynamically after the page loads, stick to doing it in Ruby

Answer (score 0):

`checked= !f.paid?` this isn't right... should be `checked: !f.paid?`.

Likewise: `id="paidrow"` and `id="price"` etc

In html, ids must be unique. If you have the same thing in multiple rows, that will break the html standard.

Try using `class` instead of `id` to match multiple similar things, and use something to uniquify the ids eg:

```
class="paidrow" id="paid_row_<%= f.id %>"
```